# Tensorflow: load_op_library load incorrectly

Tags: tensorflow, importerror

I've added a new Op (for example, it's name actv). I have a GPU core for it, so I have source files: actv.cc and actv_kernel.cu.cc. Then I compiled it (as in Adding new Op manual), so now I have actv.so. Then

```
_actv_module = tf.load_op_library('/home/<username>/test/actv.so')
print(dir(_actv_module))
```

In the output I see most important for me -- 'actv'. So, everything is fine.
Let's try do it in another directory (same sources, same compiler flags, same two lines of code):

```
_actv_module = tf.load_op_library('/home/<username>/test2/test3/actv.so')
print(dir(_actv_module))
```

And there isn't 'actv' in it. Even more, if I just copy test/actv.so to test2/test3/actv.so, problem still arises. So, two questions: 
1) What's a king of black magic? 
2) How can I make such loading by relative path?

Comment: are you sure the path is correct? I've been [using load_op_library](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/memory_probe_ops) by copying `.so` to `.` that has worked so far

Comment: Path is correct. If path would be incorrect, i'd have another error message "couldn't find file...", something like that

Comment: what if you try to load it from "."?

Comment: No changes. load_op_library locates file, loads it, but removes all ops from it.

Comment: if this is easy to reproduce, may be worth filing a bug, with actv.so attached

Comment: Ok, looks like I have no other choice...